# What is the other number in the alarm notification?

Tags: alarm, clock

I set up an alarm (using Google Now) for 55 minutes, so the end time was around 20:13 (and therefore the start time was 19:18

When I looked at the alarm notification, there's another little number in the right hand side which said 19:43 (so 30 minutes before the time the alarm was set for)

It would make sense if it was the start time (19:18) but by itself it makes no sense.

Edit: I just tried it again and the same thing happened. I set the alarm for 55 minutes at 20:36, and it says 20:36 on the right hand side of the notification, then when there's 30 minutes left, it changed to 21:01 (which is 30 minutes before the end time)

Comment: Is it just the current time?

Comment: @eldarerathis nope, it seems to be the time the alarm was set, and then for some reason it changes when it gets to 30 minutes before the alarm time.

Comment: What happens when you set the alarm for longer than 1 hour? Have you gone into device settings>time & date and make sure set time is correct with automatic time from internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time on the right-side of the notification is, just like all other notifications, the time when the notification appears.

The alarm notification is a new feature from [Android stock Clock app on KitKat](http://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-clock-app-has-subtle-impressive-feature).

> Google's latest Clock app ... now notifies you two hours ahead of when your alarm is set to go off ...

The clock app will display the first notification 2 hours before, then the second one 30 minutes before the alarm goes off.

By looking at how Android works on the notification, when the notification is displayed using same ID and it's not dismissed yet, it will be updated instead and the "time when notification appears" will also be updated (overwritten) to the new (current) time.

In your case, when you set the alarm for 55 minutes, the notification appeared since it's already less than 2 hours. Assuming you didn't dismiss the notification, when the alarm was less than 30 minutes, the app updated the notification. Since there was no info changed (alarm's time & name are still the same), you wouldn't even notice that the notification was updated, except the "time when the notification appears".